# Can I travel to Thailand using a non-immigrant visa even though the purpose of the event is cancelled?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, thailand, covid-19

I am from Bangladesh. I recently applied for a non-immigrant type visa for entering Thailand for WordCamp Asia 2020 event. However, the event was cancelled recently for coronavirus outbreak.

Since my air ticket is non-refundable and hotel refund cost etc are too much, I thought why not to go there still and spend a week over there.

However, I am confused for the immigration procedure since I have got a [non-immigrant visa under ED category](http://www.thaiembassy.org/london/en/services/7742/84508-Non-Immigrant-visas.html#4), so I may not be allowed to travel after the event was cancelled.

So, do any one of you have similar experience and suggest me anything on this?

Comment: What visa do you have? You should specify the exact visa type you applied (and that you got). -- Note: your site is about people applying from UK (or Ireland), and most of visa requires UK (or Ireland) citizenship. Are you in UK?

Comment: As mentioned, I applied for a non-immigrant visa under the ED category which is specifically for business or conference. The link in the question will redirect you on the relevant page to find more information about the relevant visa.

Comment: The link has so many different non-immigrant visas under ED, and it lists requirements for UK citizen (which you are not). Ask the organisator. Maybe they will do a small event (for local and people who cannot cancel). Else try to contact your embassy and upgrade the visa (or get refund, some airlines allow it for free, because of coronavirus).

Comment: Do you have travel insurance? It's not sure and it depends how inclusive it is, but if the answer to this question is no then you might be able to claim back the expenses

Comment: No, I don't have any travel insurance. I'll call the embassy here tomorrow to see if they have any information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### you may travel on non-ed visa *already* issued.

If the [non-ed] visa itself is already issued in the passport, you will enter as normal and get 89 days + day of arrival permission to stay. Make sure to have 20k THB *equivalent* in cash or traveler's cheques just in case immigration asks for proof of ability to support oneself.

Enjoy your holiday.

Related: Will you be able to extend your permission to stay at a local immigration office??  Unlikely as you wouldnt have a school/event/etc.  to give you a reason to extend.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm writing this comment from Bangkok :) I had no issues at all to complete the immigration.

Comment: @md mazedul enjoy the Land of Smiles